# How to use the SQL REPLACE Function, so that it will replace some text between a certain range, rather than one specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `Product` and I am trying to replace some of the values in the `Product ID` column pictured below:

| ProductID |
| --- |
| PIDLL0000074853 |
| PIDLL000086752 |
| PIDLL00000084276 |

I am familiar with the REPLACE function and have used this like so:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(ProductID, 'LL00000', '/') AS 'Product Code' 
FROM Product
```

Which returns:

| Product Code |
| --- |
| PID/74853 |
| PIDLL000086752 |
| PID/084276 |

There will always be there letter L in the ProductID twice `LL`. However, the zeros range between 4-6. The `L` and `0` should be replaced with a `/`.

If anyone could suggest the best way to achieve this, it would be greatly appreciate. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server, so standard SQL syntax would be ideal.

Comment: Thanks for updating the OP @marc_s

Comment: Does it always *start* with `PIDLL`? Removing that, interpreting the rest as a number and adding the string again might be easiest in that case (i.e. `CONCAT('PID/', CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 0), STUFF(ProductID, 1, 5, '')))`).

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Hi @JeroenMostert, no the first three characters ```PID``` change through out the data unfortunately.

Comment: Is the first part of your data always only characters and the second part always only numbers (including the leading 0's)?

Comment: Are they always three characters? Simply adding the `LEFT(.., 3)` instead of a hard-coded `PID` is easy. If the first part is arbitrarily long it's a little more interesting.

Comment: Is the last part of the "kept" value always 5 digits? Can it be zero-filled (e.g., 01234)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

All credit goes to @JeroenMostert

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ProductID VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @tbl (ProductID) VALUES
('PIDLL0000074853'),
('PIDLL000086752'),
('PIDLL00000084276'),
('PITLL0000084770');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT * 
    , CONCAT(LEFT(ProductID,3),'/', CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 0), STUFF(ProductID, 1, 5, ''))) AS [After]
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------------+-----------+
| ID |    ProductID     |   After   |
+----+------------------+-----------+
|  1 | PIDLL0000074853  | PID/74853 |
|  2 | PIDLL000086752   | PID/86752 |
|  3 | PIDLL00000084276 | PID/84276 |
|  4 | PITLL0000084770  | PIT/84770 |
+----+------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you @Yitzhak Khabinsky currently geting the msg 'Error Converting data type varchar to numeric', within my data set, and trying to figure out why. However, I can see it works perfect with the insert statment you provided.

Comment: That's why it is so important to provide a minimal reproducible example ##1-4.

Comment: You can catch the offending ProductID as follows: `SELECT * 
 , TRY_CAST(STUFF(ProductID, 1, 5, '') AS DECIMAL(38, 0)) AS [After]
FROM @tbl;` The After column will contain NULL values for the offending ProductID.

Comment: Thank you very much, managed to find the anomaly in the data using the Try_Cast function you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't particularly pretty in T-SQL, as it doesn't support regex or even pattern replacement. Therefore you method is to use things like `CHARINDEX` and `PATINDEX` to find the start and end positions and then replace (don't read `REPLACE`) that part of the text.

This uses `CHARINDEX` to find the `'LL'`, and then `PATINDEX` to find the first non `'0'` character after that position. As `PATINDEX` doesn't support a start position I have to use `STUFF` to remove the first characters.

Then, finally, we can use `STUFF` (again) to replace the length of characters with a single `'/'`:

```sql
SELECT STUFF(V.ProductID,CI.I+2,ISNULL(PI.I,0),'/')
FROM (VALUES('PIDLL0000074853'),
            ('PIDLL000086752'),
            ('PIDLL00000084276'),
            ('PIDLL3246954384276'))V(ProductID)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('LL',V.ProductID),0)))CI(I)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0]%',STUFF(V.ProductID,1,CI.I+2,'')),1)))PI(I);
```

Comment: Thank you for your awnser @Larnu, however PI isn't always at the start of the string.

Comment: @LloydThomas  I don't see your point, the above isn't reliant on `'PI'` being at the start. The only characters it "cares" about are `'LL'`, which you explicitly state *"There will always be there letter L in the ProductID twice LL."* and then the first non`'0'` character after those 2 L's.

Answer (score 0):

If you are always starting with "PIDLL", you can just remove the "PIDLL", cast the rest as an INT to lose the leading 0's, then append the front of the string with "PID/". One line of code.

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @t TABLE (ProductID VARCHAR(40));
INSERT @t VALUES('PIDLL0000074853'),('PIDLL000086752'),('PIDLL00000084276');

-- Solution
SELECT t.ProductID, NewProdID = 'PID/'+LEFT(CAST(REPLACE(t.ProductID,'PIDLL','') AS INT),20)
FROM   @t AS t;
```

**Returns:**

```
ProductID          NewProdID
------------------ ----------------
PIDLL0000074853    PID/74853
PIDLL000086752     PID/86752
PIDLL00000084276   PID/84276
```